# Jenkins Pipeline parameter: list of available git repositories

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to create a pipeline, where one of the parameters is a git repository from a list of available repositories. The list would be similar to the one you see when creating a multibranch pipeline with a bitbucket repository.

[image: This list as a parameter of a build]

Is there a plugin that can do this? Is it hard to make one for myself?

Comment: Thanks, it works great. You want to write an ansqwer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shoild think the relatively new [REST List Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rest-list-parameter) would work in these circumstances, as long as the repository host supports the [plugin authentication](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rest-list-parameter/#auth-configuration) mechanisms. It's kind of an [HTTP Request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request/) extension for [Build with Parameters](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters/) plugin.

Plugin author (not me) is very responsive to positive feeback and useful enhancement requests.